# Is there any way to draw a neural network's connections in a nice way?

Tags: neural-networks, resource-request, javascript

I've been working with neural networks and artificial intelligence for a while. What I'm trying to do right now is, from a genotype I have (a sum of sensors, neurons and actuators) draw how the neural network is (with recurrent/recursive connections being showed nicely, etc.)

What I have done now in javascript is this:

[image: I know, its ugly]

I have achieved this using [SigmaJs](http://sigmajs.org/), a Javascript drawing library, but I think it's still ugly, and what I'm looking for is a node drawing library that can achieve recursive connections in a nice way (right now, I'm drawing them with a red color as you can see on the image).

I have examined a lot of GitHub repositories and websites that can be helpful but aren't worth it since they aren't that nice.

Has anyone got an idea of what can I use, in javascript?  If not, in any other language, how can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the developer of [Neataptic](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic), a Javascript neural network library. I don't know if it is exactly what you're looking for, but it has a built-in graph creator using [D3](https://d3js.org/) and [webcola](http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/).

Basically, each connection gets an arrow. It also supports self-connections and gates.

There are some examples of images:

[image]

[image]

Play around yourself [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ch8s9d3e/29/).

Answer (score 2):

You might have come across the [Tensorflow Playground](http://playground.tensorflow.org/) which has a wonderful visualization of the network connections and the neuron weights.

Their code is available in GitHub ([here](https://github.com/tensorflow/playground)), and the code seems fairly simple. It is coded in typescript but that can be easily transpiled to pure JavaScript.